# Number of ways to arrange people in two rows, so that nobody stands behind or to the right of someone taller

Tags: combinatorics

How many ways are there to arrange $2n$ people (no two of them being the same height) in 2 rows of $n$ people, so that:

1. the people in each row are ordered by height, with the shortest on the left and the tallest on the right, and
2. each person in the rear row is taller than the corresponding person in the front row?

For example, for four people (numbered from 1 to 4 in ascending order of height), I see only two possible arrangements:

- front row = (1, 2), rear row = (3, 4); or
- front row = (1, 3), rear row = (2, 4).

If there is no closed-form solution, does a recurrence relation exist?

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange! I've edited your question to clarify its meaning, but I'm not 100% sure I understood it correctly myself. Please check if the rewritten question matches what you meant to ask, and if not, please edit it yourself (or try to explain what you meant by commenting here). Thanks!

Comment: @IlmariKaronen, everything is correct, thank you very much. I am not native english.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen, I have realized that I missed one condition. Could you moderate my question again, thank you.

Comment: @bof, look at rows: 1 > 4(ok), 2 > 3(ok); look at columns: 2 > 1(ok) , 3 < 4(not ok)

Comment: @bof 4 > 3 person ahead should be shorter

Comment: For some reason I was confused, but I think I understand the question now. If you have a partially ordered set which is the direct product of an $n$-element chain and a $2$-element chain (the Hasse diagram looks like a ladder), in how many ways can the partial order be extended to a linear order? Is that right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the number of $2\times n$ standard Young tableaux, which is given by

the Catalan numbers: $\;\;$ $\displaystyle C_n=\frac{1}{n+1}\binom{2n}{n}$.

(If you let the numbers in the first row correspond to votes for candidate A, and the numbers in the second row correspond to votes for candidate B, you get the number of ways the votes can be counted with candidate A never getting behind candidate B in the count.)

Comment: As an additional comment, note that if you apply the hook-length formula to this shape, you immediately get that formula for the Catalan numbers.

Comment: @user84413 can you explain it, when I have 2n people and want to count how many ways can these people be limed up in two rows of length n so everyone in the 1st row is taller than the corresponding person in the second row?

Comment: @A.Rex  can you help in this?